# How to delete my Facebook developer account

Tags: account-management, facebook-developers

I have deleted my Facebook account, and so  I log in messenger with my phone number. Now I feel like it **still** logs me on with an older Facebook account I used to have.

I failed to remember this Facebook developer account. Now I think it just gives me problems.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/
2. Enter Your facebook **username** and **password**
3. Go to **Contact** page https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/contact/
4. In **Contact** page Scroll bottom to see **Delete Developer Account** Panel
5. Click **Delete Account** Button
6. Finally **click Save Changes** button

Note:If you're the only admin of an app, the app will be deleted as well.